# Constant width in ggplot barplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar

How to make the width of bars and spaces between them fixed for several barplots using `ggplot`, having different number of bars on each plot?

Here is a failed try:

```
m <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=runif(10))
ggplot(m, aes(x,y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(m[1:3,], aes(x,y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Adding `width=1` to `geom_bar(...)` doesn't help as well. I need the second plot automatically to have less width and the same bar width and spaces as the first one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:**

It appears the OP simply wants this:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1,arrangeGrob(p2,widths=c(1,2),ncol=2), ncol=1)
```

---

I am not sure, if it's possible to pass absolute widths to `geom_bar`. So, here is an ugly hack:

```
set.seed(42)
m <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=runif(10))
p1 <- ggplot(m, aes(x,y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
p2 <- ggplot(m[1:3,], aes(x,y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)
```

I used `str` to find the correct grob and child. You could use more sophisticated methods to generalize this if necessary.

```
#store the old widths
old.unit <- g2$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$width[[1]]

#change the widths
g2$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$width <- rep(g1$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$width[[1]],
                                         length(g2$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$width))

#copy the attributes (units)
attributes(g2$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$width) <- attributes(g1$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$width)

#position adjustment (why are the bars justified left???)
d <- (old.unit-g2$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$width[[1]])/2
attributes(d) <- attributes(g2$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$x)
g2$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$x <- g2$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$x+d

#plot
grid.arrange(g1,g2)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, is there anyway just to shrink the width of the plot - to have bar width and spaces constant?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you want to achieve. Maybe adjust the scale limits?

Comment: I have updated the question. I need the bar width and spaces between bars are the same in two plots (so the second plot width is about .3 of the first automatically). how adjusting scale limits can help me to achieve the goal? have you an example?

Comment: Would `grid.arrange(p1,arrangeGrob(p2,widths=c(1,2),ncol=2), ncol=1)` suit your needs? I'm sure it could be done programmatically, but frankly I don't see any effort from your side, which doesn't motivate me.

Comment: Thanks, your comment is just perfect. You may add it to your answer and I will be happy to mark it accepted

Comment: @Ali I have added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapped the other suggestions in a function that only requires a single graph.

```
fixedWidth <- function(graph, width=0.1) {
  g2 <- graph

  #store the old widths
  old.unit <- g2$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$width[[1]]
  original.attibutes <- attributes(g2$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$width)

  #change the widths
  g2$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$width <- rep(width,
                                           length(g2$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$width))

  #copy the attributes (units)
  attributes(g2$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$width) <- original.attibutes

  #position adjustment (why are the bars justified left???)
  d <- (old.unit-g2$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$width[[1]])/2
  attributes(d) <- attributes(g2$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$x)
  g2$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$x <- g2$grobs[[4]]$children[[2]]$x+d

  return(g2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem with:

```
mywidth = .5
ggplot(m, aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_col(width=log(1 + length(unique(m$x))) * mywidth)
```

Because geom_bar() tries to adjust bar width based on how many unique values there are of the x-axis variable, log() "undoes" this by rapidly increasing as the number of unique values of x increases, "flattening" the cumulative geom_bar() + custom width to a constant value.

The 1 + is just to deal with log(1)=0.

You can adjust the value of mywidth as you like.