# Keeping the width constant in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Have already tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429244/constant-width-in-ggplot-barplots) but it fails to work, moreover this question was asked 5 years ago so I hope there is a better way around than this lengthy code.

**How to make the width of bars and spaces between them fixed for several barplots using ggplot, having different number of bars on each plot?**

```
#with 10 bins
data <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=runif(10))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")

#with 3 bins
ggplot(data[1:3,], aes(x,y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Adding width=1 to geom_bar(...) doesn't help as well. I need the second plot automatically to have less width and the same bar width and spaces as the first one.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:shiny]?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to adjust the coordinates to match:

```
ggplot(data[1:3,], aes(x,y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.5,10)) # This is approximate but pretty close.
#
# For an exact match, you can go into the ggplot_build object and
# extract [["layout"]][["panel_params"]][[1]][["x.range"]]
# You could then use the exact values:
# scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.055,10.945), expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

Another would be to combine the bars into one plot, and then use facets to show the data on the same scale.

```
library(dplyr)
data2 <- 
  data %>% mutate(plot = "A") %>%
  bind_rows(
    data[1:3,] %>% mutate(plot = "B")
  )

(a <- ggplot(data2, aes(x,y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(~plot)
)
```

If you want to use this with plotly, you could then use `plotly::ggplotly(a)`.
 [image]

Comment: I tried above but facet_share does not work with ggplotly. Can anyone please suggest a way to eliminate most of the white spaces in my original question above ?

Comment: `facet_wrap` and `facet_grid` do work with `ggplotly` in my experience. Please see updated answer. (BTW it would be helpful to mention `ggplotly` in your question if it is one of your requirements.)