# RMarkdown adjust height to keep bar spacing equal with plots in a loop in a single chunk

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr

In the following RMarkdown, I would like to have each barplot print so that the text size and box width are the same in each plot, and the height adjusts accordingly.

What is happening is that in the plots with few bars the bars are extremely wide, and in the plots with many bars the bars are thin and the labels squished.

````
---
title: "chunk plot height"
number_sections: yes
output: html_notebook
---

# Load Libraries
\```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(rmarkdown)
\```


# Set Knitr Options
\```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  echo=TRUE,
  dpi=300,
  fig.width=12
)
\```

# Plot
\```{r}
for (n in seq(10,50,10))
{
  knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.height=n)

  data = data.frame(
    X=sapply(c(letters, LETTERS)[1:n], function(x) rep(x,3) %>% paste0(collapse=''), USE.NAMES = F),
    Y=rnorm(n)
  )

  plt = 
    data %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=X, y=Y)) +
    geom_col(position=position_dodge(width=1, preserve='single')) + 
    coord_flip()

  print(plt)
}
\```
````

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possibly helpful idea here even though it's a different issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255579/how-can-i-make-consistent-width-plots-in-ggplot-with-legends, or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429244/constant-width-in-ggplot-barplots

Comment: Those look useful. But pretty complex. In my old Matlab days, I could specify bar width and plot aspect ratio declaratively.

Comment: Yeah, R doesn’t work that way sadly. I’d designed to scale to any graphics device size. A ggplot doesn’t have much control over its own size in R. But in most cases this is a very useful behavior.

Comment: `fig.height='auto'` would be great.