R, ggplot2: How to get same X axis unit scale?
How can I use the same "X axis scale" for multiple plots using R and ggplot2?
i.e. given the following two plots, I want the second one to be twice as wide as the first one, as it has twice as many bars (limits can be different, but "unit step" should have same real length, as well as bar size):

Code used to create the plots:
##### set work directory to script directory
getwd()
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
getwd()

##### load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

##### create dataset 1
gender <- c('M','F','M','F','M','F')
type <- factor(c('A','A','B','B','C','C'))
value <- c(11,22,33,44,55,66)
data1 <- data.frame(gender,type,value)


##### create dataset 2
gender <- c('M','F','M','F','M','F','M','F','M','F','M','F')
type <- factor(c('A','A','B','B','C','C','D','D','E','E','F','F'))
value <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
data2 <- data.frame(gender,type,value)

##### create plots
p1 <- ggplot(data = data1, aes(x = type, y = value, fill=gender)) + geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
p2 <- ggplot(data = data2, aes(x = type, y = value, fill=gender)) + geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')

##### combine plots
p1+p2


Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429244/constant-width-in-ggplot-barplots? It would probably be easier to combine your data into a single faceted plot. ggplot objects don't have an inherent width. The are "liquid" and stretch to fill whatever space you give them.

Thanks. That looks like the same problem. I haven't had too much success yet with the suggestions there. Is it easier if I use ggsave() to save the plots to a specific size? (which I intended to do anyway) Alternatively, what would be better than ggplot to do this then?

We can combine the two tables, noting the source, and then use that source to facet. facet_grid allows you to scale the facets based on the axis of each facet, in this case varying the scale and the physical space on x (hence "free_x").
ggplot(dplyr::bind_rows(d1 = data1, d2 = data2, .id = "src"),
       aes(x = type, y = value, fill=gender)) +
  geom_col(position='dodge') +
  facet_grid(.~src, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")



Thank you! I was hoping for separate figures, but this works nicely enough. Is it possible to linewrap the text in the labels (d1,d,2,d3)? Or not show them (so I can cut the generated image into pieces and do labeling in LaTeX)?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654691/how-to-dynamically-wrap-facet-label-using-ggplot2

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547487/remove-facet-wrap-labels-completely
